# Editing large c# file becomes impossible when PostSharp extenstion is installed, even if the solution doesn't use postsharp.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, postsharp

I'm on Visual Studio 2013 trying to edit a large c# file - 434KB. 
Collapsing\expanding a region takes time. Even scrolling through the file hangs the IDE. Code completion, and editing also a pain...
After uninstalling the PostSharp extension IDE works smoothly with this file.
This particular solution doesn't use the PostSharp.dll.

Is there any option to disable the extension per solution?

Thank you

Comment: If the large size is causing other issues (like collapsing/expanding taking a long time), perhaps you could break it into several files? You can use partial class files to do it without having to change any code logic. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx

Comment: Could be a solution, but I have more files like this, and auto-generated-big-ones. Would be most simple just to disable the extension without touching any files...

Comment: I know it's not what you want to hear, but code files that size are rather antisocial. What's in them?

Comment: They contain code that runs in production. Basically it's an html rendering engine based on xml. Old pain...

Comment: We'll look at it. As a workaround, is it possible for you to use VS2015?

Comment: Great idea. It appears that there is no issue in VS2015. Thank you.

Comment: The issue has been fixed for VS2013 in PostSharp 4.2.18. Please update your PostSharp Visual Studio extension to the latest version.